# C# codeDom errors

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I am trying to compile code with codeDom with this function:

```
   public static bool Compile(string Output, string Source, string Icon, string resources)
   {
      CompilerParameters Parameters = new CompilerParameters();
      CompilerResults cresults = default(CompilerResults);
      Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");
      CSharpCodeProvider Compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
      Parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
      Parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
      Parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
      Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add("System");

      Parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe /platform:x86";
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Icon))
      {
         Parameters.CompilerOptions += " /win32icon" + Icon;
      }
      cresults = Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Parameters, Source);

      if (cresults.Errors.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (CompilerError compile_error in cresults.Errors)
         {
            CompilerError error = compile_error;
            MessageBox.Show(error + "");
         }
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

source has these libarys (not sure if it's libarys I'm rather a java develloper):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using Dns = System.Net.Dns;
using AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

But when I compile I get these errors:

```
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(3,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(4,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(5,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(6,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(8,26) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Specialized' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(9,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(16,14) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ComponentModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(10,20) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(11,30) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\Augustin\AppData\Local\Temp\odq0sdk5.0.cs(60,14) : error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I solve these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you didn't add referenced assemblies. All these errors are related to another assembly that should be added:

```
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll"); // System, System.Net, etc namespaces
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll"); // System.Data namespace
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.SQLite.dll"); // System.Data.SqlLite namespace
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll"); // System.Xml namespace
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll"); // System.Windows.Forms namespace
```

If your code uses these namespaces, then all appropriate assemblies should be added to ReferencedAssemblies collection

PS. I don't know what is correct assembly name for SQLite assembly, as I guess it's System.Data.SQLite.dll, but I can be wrong

Comment: `error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Net.dll' could not be found`

Comment: yep. I've mistaken. It should be just System.dll. I've updated answer

Comment: What dll should I use for System.Resources?

Comment: Based on that article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx it's in mscorlib.dll, but I suppose it should be linked automatically

Comment: `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Recource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: When i specified `using System.Resources;` in my sample program, then it compiled fine with ReferencedAssemblies from my answer. If it still reproduces for you, you need to update your question with sample code that doesn't work